# Dell DCU-Cli.exe missing after upgrading to universal update 4.7.1

Tags: windows, dell

I have a problem with the Dell update tools. Up until now I've been pushing out a combination of Dell Update and Dell Command | update to end up with both a

The latest Dell Update Universal, version 4.7.1 (exe name `Dell-Update-Windows-Universal-Application_0991N_WIN_4.7.1_A00.EXE`), seems to remove older versions of both Dell Update and Dell Command | Update, leaving me with just Dell Update 4.7.1 installed

However, this does not install into `c:\program files\Dell` or `c:\program files (x86)\dell` like the older installers. Instead it is appearing under

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\DellInc.DellCommandUpdate_4.7.18.0_x86__htrsf667h5kn2\DCU.Classic.
```

The problem is, this folder doesn't include the dcu-cli tool

I've tried pushing out

```
Dell-Command-Update-Windows-Universal-Application_CJ0G9_WIN_4.7.1_A00.EXE
```

to machines where its missing, but its failing on loads of machines. The install log reports :

```
Property(S): UnSupportedOSDetected = Aborting the installation process as the application is not supported on your operating system.
```

This is occuring on machines which are more or less new, like 'Vostro 15 3510'

So we can assume that its not actually universal.

I can't find anything which indicates what I should be installing to get a command line tool to check for updates. I don't mind which one we have to use, I just need to automate it and I'd prefer the same tool for all models, obviously.

Comment: I don't work any client but I don't mind asking around internally when I get the chance if you want to shoot me an e-mail. https://grantcurell.github.io/#questions. If you open a support case against it I can also keep tabs on it

Comment: Please don't add `Solved` to the title and edit the solution into the question. Instead, post it as an answer and accept it. Otherwise the question will stay as `unsolved` in the system forever and pop up again and again.

Comment: ok, no problem. A lot of places seem to edit the original question and insert the answer into the question, adding 'solved' to the title. I'll reedit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems mentioned in this post all disappeared in subsequent versions of dcu. New ones appeared, but the missing dcu-cli.exe is not one of the problems I've seen again.